# How to get paginated_data_table to respect the parent widget's maxWidth property?

Tags: flutter

If I have long text in a `PaginatedDataTable` widget the text is not wrapped like in a `DataTable`.  Usually, for a widget I'd fix this by adding BoxConstraints to set a max width of the parent.  However PaginatedDataTable internally surrounds a DataTable with a SingleChildScrollView and removes the parent's max width constraints.

Here is part of the PaginatedDataTable's code

```
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            primary: widget.primary,
            controller: widget.controller,
            dragStartBehavior: widget.dragStartBehavior,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: constraints.minWidth),
              child: DataTable(
                key: _tableKey,
```

I want to wrap the long text in the 2nd column when it gets too big, exactly as DataTable does automatically.  How do I do this?  As you can see with PaginatedDataTable more text is lost and the third column is too far on the right.

I've created a gist & dartpad to show the different behaviours.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=0559d2989c161fdbc13995ef508c56ea

[image]

Comment: In these situations would it be a good idea to copy and paste the PaginatedDataTable widget and just add the max width constraint?  Or possibly add a request to the Flutter team?